# Unity игнорирует зажимание клавиши в FixedUpdate/Update

Tags: unity3d

Я начинающий разработчик на Unity, и изучаю структуру кода, путем написания примитивных скриптиков.
Так вот, решил я одним из скриптов наделить куб на сцене уникальной возможностью перемещаться. Однако, ничего не вышло, потому что код реализован путем добавления в Update if (Input.GetKeyDown("w")) и действие на один микро-шаг.
Проблема в том, что Unity игнорирует факт зажатия клавиши, и для каждого шага нужно индивидуально нажимать кнопку.
Путем проб и ошибок, долго копавшись, я понял что проблема не в коде, так как он же стабильно работает на других устройствах, в движке Unity.
Следовательно, что-то не так с настройками самого движка или, не дай бог, самой Unity.

Что может вызывать такую ошибку? Есть возможности исправить это?

Comment: Если ответ вам помог,то отметьте его.Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Проблема не в коде

Проблема в коде:
Если вы хотите проверять в Update зажата ли клавиша,то нужно использовать не

```
Input.GetKeyDown("w") // Возращает true если клавиша нажата(pressed)
```

А

```
Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W) // Возращает true если клавиша зажата(hold)
```

Пример из скрипта:

```
void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) {
            transform.position = new Vector2 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 0.1f);
        }
        else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            transform.position = new Vector2 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 0.1f);
        }
        else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            transform.position = new Vector2 (transform.position.x - 0.1f, transform.position.y);
        }

        else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            transform.position = new Vector2 (transform.position.x + 0.1f, transform.position.y);
        }
    }
```

***Ps: пример для 2D,для 3D нужно использовать Vector3(и добавить z координату)***

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html

Comment: Именно. GetKeyDown и GetKeyUp - для единичного действия. Просто GetKey - для многократного.

Comment: @АлексейПетродий, вы не совсем правильно описали эти методы. `GetKey` возвращает true, пока зажата клавиша, `GetKeyDown` возвращает true в течении ровно 1 кадра вне зависимости, зажата ли клавиша. Никакой "многократности" здесь нет.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, немного не так, GetKeyDown выдает true в тот момент, когда пользователь только-только нажал клавишу. Именно опустил. А так да, ровно 1 кадр, многократность только если быстро тыкать на кнопку))

Comment: @JetFly, я вроде так и написал, разве нет?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Я просто хотел добавить, когда именно результат true. Мне почему-то изначально показалось немного мутным описание работы. Сейчас свое перечитал, половины не понял. Извиняюсь.

Comment: @JetFly, да ничего, бывает. Я тоже не совсем точно пояснил. `GetKeyDown` возвращает true ровно один фрейм с момента нажатия кнопки.